# limit in position order by clause

Tags: mysql

How can limit in order by with random number:

```
q_id    position    qtn     level
1           1       demo      1
2           1       demo12    1
3           1       demo21    1
4           2       demo22    1
5           2       demo11    1
6           2       demo31    1
7           3       demo41    1
8           3       demo51    1
9           4       demo61    1
```

What i want is,

```
q_id    position    qtn     level
3           1       demo21    1
4           2       demo22    1
8           3       demo51    1
9           4       demo61    1
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT q_id, position, qtn, level FROM tbl WHERE level = '1' ORDER BY position, RAND()
```

How can use **LIMIT in position with ORDER BY**?

Comment: Didn't get it. Explain a bit more.

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu i want to put limit 1 in position.

Comment: it is possible using Group By http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp, but it will show data in group

Comment: @PhpDeveloper if I use `GROUP BY` then it always display first record only, not random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by if you only want 1 row per position. Note that we need to randomize the order in an inner query first:

```
SELECT q_id, position, qtn, level 
FROM (select * from Table1 order by rand()) a
WHERE level = '1' 
group by position
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c306a/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` command at the start as `SELECT DISTINCT(YOUR QUERY)` as this will help in the single entry for the position. And you can use `RAND()` in combination so that randomly the position will be selected. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT q_id, position, qtn, level 
FROM tbl WHERE level = '1' 
ORDER BY position, RAND() 
GROUP BY position Limit 4
```